# Most effective way of looping an array of size of more than a million and then insertion to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, optimization, bulkinsert

I have an `array of records` which is most likely to have a `length of million or more than that`. I need to loop it through to `select few attributes` from each record and then `bulk insert them to a table`.

The most simple version of that i have got it is like this:

```
objs = []
workers.each do |w|
  temp = {}
  temp[:person_id] = w.id
  temp[:working_hours] = time
  objs << temp
end
WorkHours.create(objs)
```

So `workers` is an array which will always consists of records more than a million. Now i need to select only some `attributes` from each `record` and then bulk insert them to a `WorkHours` table.

I need to know in what ways this code can be improved and how bulk insertion can be done here. For reference i'm using `Postgres` database and `rails 4.2`.

Got to know about this [gem](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) but not sure about it.

Comment: Where does this million record array come from?

Comment: So basically i have a datatable from where user can do the export of records. So when doing the export, the system needs to maintain the export date and time for further flow. So for each record it has to maintain the export time.

Comment: So they're in the database already? Why not leave them there and do all the work right inside the database?

Comment: Find 'workers' in batches and create them in batches.  Don't create the entire workers at one go.  Check for batches in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches. And using some schedulers to do this will be the best approach. Something like delayed job.

Comment: @muistooshort can you give me some example. ?

Comment: SQL: `insert into t1 (c1, c2) select c1, c2 from t2 where ...`

Comment: @muistooshort Ok. Thanks. It helped :). If u want you can write a proper answer. I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: You're welcome to write your own answer, I just provided a couple pointers.